# How a wheatstone bridge is used in operational amplifiers?

Tags: operational-amplifier, wheatstone-bridge, bridge

How a wheatstone bridge is used  in operational amplifiers?

Comment: It is not. I challenge you to show me an opamp **with a Wheatstone bridge inside the circuit of the opamp**. If you search for "Wheatstone bridge opamp" you will find example circuits where a Wheatstone bridge is combined with an opamp.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please show at least one example of such a circuit. Otherwise your question is too unspecific to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of the Wheatstone bridge can be seen, for example, in op-amp circuits with both negative and positive feedback, e.g., the so-called "negative impedance converter" (NIC).

[image: Negative impedance converter (INIC) presented as a bridge]

Indeed, it is a guite strange bridge... but it is still a bridge...

[image: INIC asd a bridge - conceptual circuit diagram]